# Ruby Mysql Crashing

Tags: mysql, ruby

My ruby code crashes on this code

```
puts "one"
con = Mysql.real_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database')
puts "two"
```

It outputs one but not two??
Why isn't it executing any further

Answer (score 0):

Add `require "mysql"` at the beginning.

Also check if you can connect to your database (other than from ruby), just to check that its actually running.

**EDIT:**
Also, use exception handling to catch these subtle errors.

Comment: Oops it was that. I had commented it.